# Как получить номер мобильного телефона android?

Tags: java, android

Как достать номер телефона? Какой нибудь способ 100% вывести номер телефона (самому пользователю не доверяю)

Comment: 100% способа нет. Скажу больше -- на бОльшинстве устройств номер достать не получится.

Comment: К тому же, не во всех Android устройствах есть возможность использовать сим карту. Раз не доверяете пользователю, делайте подтверждение номера по коду в смс. Это гораздо более надёжный способ, чем то, что хотите вы.

Answer (score 0):

Код:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)appContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String phoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
```

Требуется пермишен:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

**Disclaimer:** работает не на всех телефонах.

Comment: я так пробова. Не знаете случайно на каких именно не работает?

Comment: А со стороны гугла вопросов не возникает?

Comment: скороее всего и не со всеми симкартами